# Vue.js How can I pass an empty object as props to the same form (create/update)?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to use the same form to create and update an object.

In my page, I am passing in all colors like this:

```
<my-form-component :colors="colors" :foo="foo" />
```

My form component looks like this:

```
// MyFormComponent.vue

<input type="text" v-model="foo.name" />

<select id="colorId" v-model="foo.colorId">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option v-for="color in colors"
            :key="color.id"
            :value="color.id">
            {{ color.name }}
    </option>
</select>

...

<script>
    ...

    props: {
        colors: {
            type: Array,
            required: true,
        },
        foo: {
            type: Object,
            required: false,
            default: undefined,
        },
    }
</script>
```

When I am *editing* my object `foo` everything works great! I am passing in foo & colors as as props.

The problem is when creating a new object, `foo` doesn't exist (obviously) so I am getting an error, "TypeError: Cannot read property 'colorId' of undefined"

I understand exactly why it is angry--since I am not passing in `foo`, it does not have `colorId`.

If I create a `foo` data object, I get an error that since I am passing `foo` as props, use that instead.

How can I pass in an empty object as props so I do not get the undefined error? Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Default accepts a factory function:

```
props: {
  foo: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => ({})
  }
}
```

See [Prop Validation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation).

Relevant bit:

```
...
  // Object or array defaults must be returned from  
  // a factory function  
  default: function () {  
    return { message: 'hello' }  
  }
...
```

Comment: Ah shoot! I had set up the entire object (including properties) and wasn't getting it to work. Thank you so much!